# Error occured while performing nmConnect in weblogic

Tags: python, weblogic11g, wlst

I am new to Weblogic, and I want to start the admin server using a Python script. When I try to do so, I get the following errors:

```
WLSTException: Error occured while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Node Manager. : t3://192.##.##.##. Could not connect to NodeManager. Check that it is running at t3://192.##.##.##:5556.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace**
```

I have checked with the Nodemanager.properties file and also updated the Nodemanager username and password.

Can any one help on this issue?

Comment: What is the nmConnect command you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Nagesh,

Is your Nodemanager running?
Please check that with ps command if you are in Linux/any Unix OS

```
ps -ef |grep NodeM
```

Please give us the command that you have used to connect to NodeManager. Usually the mistake would be sometime you might updated the NodeManager port not updated in the properties.